# Como pasar Arreglos entre Formularios?

Tags: c#, array, visual-studio

[image: Formulario 1 NuevaCita]

[image: Formulario 2 InformacionCliente]

Me gustaría pasar los arreglos que están en el formulario NuevaCita al Formulario InformacionCliente ya que estoy realizando un proyecto y apenas estoy aprendiendo a utilizar C#. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Por favor coloca el código como texto para que tu error se pueda reproducir fácilmente.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

es mejor cuando pegas el código en en ves de imagen con código.
Al menos yo lo haría de esta forma:

En el Formulario InformacionCLiente haría lo siguiente:
Gererar Variables con modificador pública, para poder asignarlas cuando instancies  el formulario

```
 public partial class InformacionCLiente : Form
{
    public string[] Arreglo_IdCliente = new string[10];
    public string[] Arreglo_NombreCliente = new string[10];.......
```

Y para enviar los datos desde el formulario NuevaCita a InformacionCliente deberías asignar las variables:

```
 private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FrmGestionAlmacenes frm = new FrmGestionAlmacenes();
        frm.Arreglo_IdCliente = Arreglo_IdCliente;
        frm.Arreglo_NombreCliente = Arreglo_NombreCliente;
        ...........
    }
```